# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: sql-server, maven, liquibase, mssql-jdbc, java-17

I am developing my application in SpringBoot which uses liquibase to update my ms-sql database.

This worked fine till now, but now I am trying to update everything to the latest version:

- I changed java from 15 to 17.
- I also updated liquibase-maven-plugin to 4.5.0.
- mssql-jdbc dependency for liquibase is: mssql-jdbc:9.4.0.jre16
- The new mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.0.x64.dll file is moved to this folder:
  c:\apps\Java\x64\jdk-17\bin\ (this is my java location).
- My IntelliJ is set to use java 17 (JAVA_HOME is also configured to
  the 17 path)
- the version of Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit): 11.0.2100.60

So I think I did everything, but still, when I try to run my maven, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.5.0:update (myDatabase) on project my-project: 
[ERROR] Error setting up or running Liquibase:
[ERROR] liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=My_Database;integratedSecurity=true with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]"
```

Comment: Not really a Java issue, per se, just that it's trying to connect to an old SQL Server that doesn't support TLS 1.2 or 1.3 connections. And it must be a really old (or really unpatched) SQL Server instance since even SQL Server 2008 had updates to support TLS 1.2.

Comment: But if I revert my changes, to use the older version of java and liquibase and everything, then it works fine.

Comment: and the version of the sql server is: 11.0.2100.60 (I updated the question)

Comment: Consider installing updates for your SQL Server 2012 Express instance... [KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe)

Comment: This solved the problem. Give it as an answer and I will approve it!