# Liquibase "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]"

Tags: java-8, liquibase

I have already made following changes in java.security file inside jdk :

**security.overridePropertiesFile=false** -> to make sure than nothing is getting overridden

Removed Tls entries from **jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms** key

But still Liquibase is failing with following error:

```
Starting Liquibase at 16:28:02 (version 4.11.0 #2708 built at 2022-05-23 15:17+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.11.0
Liquibase Community 4.11.0 by Liquibase

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://XYZ:1433;databaseName=ABC with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  
The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. 
Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:7a467199-42ba-4179-8313-23afcdf085c9
```

Restarted shell and even machine, tried with jdk 11 but no luck. Am using a **MAC** machine. If someone has experienced same in Liquibase, please do help.

Comment: See the comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69809628/liquibase-exception-databaseexception-connection-could-not-be-created-with-driv). Might help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes I got hold of a new test db instance having latest version of db server. I had the same issue while connecting to old db in a dockerised env and I managed to fix by editing the jdk security conf. Looks like something in Liquibase jar file OR mac settings is causing the issue.